# Monitors swapping and windows moving on PC wakeup

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, sleep

I just got a new monitor and set it up without issue accept for when the computer sleeps, the tabs get shuffled and the pc seems to mix up which monitor is which. The old monitors are the exact same model ( a 144hz 1080p 28" AOC monitors) the new one is a 160hz 34" 1440p LG. The new large one is in the middle. The display settings have the new one set to the main display (order is 213). When I wake the computer, the monitors all seem to glitch a bit while waking up before the windows get mixed up (the left one seems to not do this; I think it might be the middle one affecting the right one).Also the left and middle are on display port(1.2 I think) the right monitor is on hdmi as I didn't have another dp cable.

The tabs on the right monitor in maximized mode tend to go to the left monitor in small mode and the tabs that aren't maximized get moved to the left monitor. Tabs in the left monitor have gone to the middle or stayed in place and didn't change size. To make it more confusing, a game I play changes which monitor it wants to be displayed on despite the setting in game not changing (escape from tarkov). It was set to the LG and was still set to the LG but was opening on the right monitor. I swapped the setting to one of the AOC monitors and got the left monitor and then the other AOC monitor put it on the center LG monitor.

I've attempted to follow someone elses fix (device manager - monitors - remove extra monitors (there were none) - update drivers (they are all up to date according to windows))
I tried a different workaround where you lock the pc before it sleeps; this resulted in it waking with the buggy screens as mentioned before but once I logged in, windows were in the locations I left them.

any ideas?

PC

- I7-9700F
- 32GB ddr4 memory
- Internal SSD
- FE RTX 3070

--- UPDATE ---
So I found a solution-ish. I can remove the issue by changing some settings. I set the monitor sleep time and the pc sleep time to the same value such that when the system goes to sleep it wakes up on the lock screen. This prevents the monitors from attempting to place the windows until after everything is awake and the pc is unlocked. The downside is it forces you to the lock screen every time your system goes to sleep but that's a minor annoyance and probably better for security anyways.

Comment: How are the monitors connected (HDMI, DisplaPort) ?

Comment: It's in the post (left and middle are DisplayPort and the right one is hdmi)

Answer (score 0):

DisplayPort acts as a PNP device, so if Windows turns them off
their windows will be moved. When turned on in some random order,
the monitors will be treated as if Windows just discovered
them and windows will be shuffled among them.

You could try to prevent Windows from verifying the continued
presence of the DisplayPort monitors and so to not detect when off,
is to keep the
[Extended Display Identification Data (EDID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)
properties of the monitors.

For this solution, see these answers of mine
(you are not the only one to have had this problem):

- [GeForce GTX 980 Ti reverts to single monitor on wake up](https://superuser.com/a/1027641/8672)
- [Turning DisplayPort monitor off disables monitor completely](https://superuser.com/a/631691/8672)

If this doesn't work, you might need to arrange for the monitors
to never fall asleep, which is also not a good solution.

My last suggestion would be to save and restore the positions
of all the windows before and after the sleep by using the
AutoHotkey V1 script in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1509845/8672).

Answer (score -1):

You may consider checking the monitor that you think could cause these issues for any loose cables and ore misplaced ore missing plugs going to the computer. If you are sure that the monitors are not the problem then see if you need to do a driver update for the GPU or add more vram so your computer can potentially display the screens the appropriate way with few issues underway.
If the issue continues to persist then you must consult a experienced technician ore if some of your monitors are a very old model, then replace the old monitors with updated ones and check to see if the displays stop glitching.

Comment: Please try to give better answers that address at least the question. Just throwing everything and whatever inside your answers is not useful. That's not how one gains good reputation on our site.

Comment: no loose plugs,
already updated drivers,
Not a vram issue, it's an issue when waking from sleep.
Didn't post here for someone to tell me to consolt an experienced technician

Please don't post a copy paste, I was looking for solutions because I couldn't find one that worked online and don't want to pay someone to look at it.